# While trying to edit, system throws Cannot read property '0' of null

Tags: reactjs, express, axios, react-hooks

While trying to `edit` any of text fields throws error  `Cannot read property '0' of null` and the image also not updating to the database. Added a screen shot

TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null
handleChange

C:/Project/soccerpep/src/components/Profile.js:67
[image]

```
import React, {useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import Axios from "axios";



const Profile = () => {

  const [preview, setPreview] = useState('');
  const [picture, setPicture] = useState('');
  const [playerProfile, setPlayerProfile] = useState([]);
  const loginUserEmail = localStorage.getItem('loginEmail');
  const [updateProfile, setUpdateProfile] = useState({ _id: '', photo: '', name: '', email:'', phonenumber:'', position:'', privilege:'', password:''});
  const [isSent, setIsSent] = useState(false);
  const [helperText, setHelperText] = useState('');
  const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(true);
  const { handleSubmit, register, errors } = useForm();
  const history = useHistory();
  

  const onChangePicture = e => {
    console.log('picture: ', picture);
    if (e.target.files.length) {
      setPreview(URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]));
      setPicture({photo:e.target.files[0]});
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  };

  // Pass the id to the handler so you will know which item id changing.
  const handleChange = (e, id) => {
    e.persist();
    let itemIndex;
    const targetPlayer = playerProfile.find((player, index) => {
      console.log({ player, id, index });
      itemIndex = index; 
      return player.id === id;
    });

    console.log({ targetPlayer, id, e });

    const editedTarget = {
      ...targetPlayer,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    };
    const tempPlayers = Array.from(playerProfile);
    tempPlayers[itemIndex] = editedTarget;
    setPlayerProfile(tempPlayers);
    setUpdateProfile({ ...updateProfile, [e.target.name]: e.target.value }); // this is added just to see if its working
    setPicture({photo:e.target.files[0]});
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const params = {
          email: loginUserEmail,
        };
      const res = await Axios.get('http://localhost:8000/service/profile', {params});
        setPlayerProfile(res.data.playerProfile);
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const onSubmit = () => {

    setDisabled(disabled);
    const formData = new FormData();

    for(let key in updateProfile) {
      formData.append(key,updateProfile[key]);
    }

    if (picture) formData.append("photo", picture);

    const config = {
      headers: {
          'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
      }
    }

    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const params = {
          email: loginUserEmail,
        };
        const res = await Axios.put('http://localhost:8000/service/profile', formData, {params}, config); 
        console.log("Front End update message:" + res.data.success);
        if (res.data.success) {
          setIsSent(true);
          history.push('/')
        }
        else {
          console.log(res.data.message);
          setHelperText(res.data.message);
        }
      } catch (e) {
        setHelperText(e.response.data.message);
      }
    }
    fetchData();
  }

  return (
    <div className="register_wrapper">
      <div className="register_player_column_layout_one">
        <div className="register_player_Twocolumn_layout_two">
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className="myForm" encType="multipart/form-data">
            {
              playerProfile.map(({ id, photo, name, email, phonenumber, position, privilege, password }) => (
                <div key={id}>
                  <div className="formInstructionsDiv formElement">
                    <h2 className="formTitle">Profile</h2>
                    <div className="register_profile_image">
                      <input id="profilePic" name="photo" type="file" onChange={onChangePicture} />
                    </div>
                    <div className="previewProfilePic" >
                      <img alt="" onError={addDefaultSrc} name="previewImage" className="playerProfilePic_home_tile" src={photo} onChange={e => handleChange(e, id)}></img>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="fillContentDiv formElement">
                   <label>
                      <input className="inputRequest formContentElement" name="phonenumber" type="text" value={phonenumber} 
                      onChange={e => handleChange(e, id)}
                      maxLength={11}
                      ref={register({
                        required: "Phone number is required",
                        pattern: {
                          value: /^[0-9\b]+$/,
                          message: "Invalid phone number"
                        }
                       })}
                      />
                      <span className="registerErrorTextFormat">{errors.phonenumber && errors.phonenumber.message}</span>
                    </label>
                    </div>
                            // rest of the form fields.....
                  <div className="submitButtonDiv formElement">
                    <button type="submit" className="submitButton">Save</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              ))
            }
          </form>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Profile;
```

Comment: How can you expect `files` property on an event object called on `input` field with `type=text` ?

Comment: Sorry I did get it, even i have uploaded a new image and try to edit the any of text field it is giving the above error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`handleChange` function is being used on input `type="text"` which definitely doesn't return you files in target object and hence you see the error.

You are already using another event handler function for `input type="file"` so you need not have any image handling in `handleChange`. Also note that you don't need onChange on `img` tag

```
   const onChangePicture = e => {
    if (e.target.files.length) {
      setPreview(URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]));
      setUpdateProfile({ ...updateProfile, previewImage: e.target.files[0] });
      setPicture({photo:e.target.files[0]});
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  };


// Pass the id to the handler so you will know which item id changing.
  const handleChange = (e, id) => {
    e.persist();
    let itemIndex;
    const targetPlayer = playerProfile.find((player, index) => {
      console.log({ player, id, index });
      itemIndex = index; 
      return player.id === id;
    });

    console.log({ targetPlayer, id, e });

    const editedTarget = {
      ...targetPlayer,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    };
    const tempPlayers = Array.from(playerProfile);
    tempPlayers[itemIndex] = editedTarget;
    setPlayerProfile(tempPlayers);
    setUpdateProfile({ ...updateProfile, [e.target.name]: e.target.value }); // this is added just to see if its working
    // setPicture({photo:e.target.files[0]}); This isn't needed here
  };
```

Comment: Thank you mate, but the image still is not updating, I have choose a new image, but I couldn't see that gets updated.

Comment: It seems that you would need to update updateProfile value within onChangeProfile function

Comment: Should I create another onChangeProfile function ?

Comment: I already have `onChangePicture` function..so could I do with that ?

Comment: Yes, you can use the onChangePicture function and update the profile data `setUpdateProfile({ ...updateProfile, previewImage: e.target.files[0] });`

Comment: Are you familiar with association of models in Sequelize tables.Can you advise me to identify the issue with one question?